# Find Farbtastic color picker current value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know how to find the current value chosen when using the farbtastic color picker?  My current code is:

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');

   var curColor = $.farbtastic('#colorpicker').color; 

$('#color').change(function () {
                            curColor = $.farbtastic('#colorpicker').color;
            });
```

I firstly initialise the app and place its contents in a div called colorpicker with the input of #color.  I simply want the variable called curColor to hold the current value of the color picker at all times and update as it changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Farbtastic](https://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/) allows you to register a callback function to be called when the color is changed. And that is exactly what you need to do. Like that:

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function(color) {
    console.log('The user has just selected the following color: ' + color);
});
```

Oh, and if you would like to show the color in an input, or any other element, you can change the previous example to be like that:

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function(color) {
    console.log('The user has just selected the following color: ' + color);
    // setting input value
    $('#colorpicker').val(color);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Bruno